# WPF slider's Tooltip StringFormat doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a slider and I want to display his value on the ToolTip.

As slider's Value property is a double, ToolTip display like "12.12548565". I just want to display a rounded value ("12")

I've tried :

```
<Slider x:Name="sldAnalogSetPoint"
        Maximum="100"
        ValueChanged="sldAnalogSetPoint_ValueChanged"
        Cursor="Arrow"
        ToolTip="{Binding Value, ElementName=sldAnalogSetPoint, StringFormat=/{0:D/}}"/>
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/the-stringformat-property/) or the [MSDN page on formatting strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The Binding's StringFormat is ignored, because the type of the target property (ToolTip) isn't string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use  **IsSnapToTickEnabled** and **TickFrequency** properties fo slider:

[How do you make a WPF slider snap only to discrete integer positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173009/how-do-you-make-a-wpf-slider-snap-only-to-discrete-integer-positions)

ToolTip:

```
ToolTip="{Binding Value, ElementName=sldAnalogSetPoint}"

<Slider ... IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="1"/>
```

You can also use Converter(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) for your binding. But that will be bad solution.